# Magento 2 - Data Migration Tool

Tags: magento2, products, data-migration

Does magento 2 data migration tool migrate disabled products from Magento 1 database?

I know all the products data is migrated from Magento 1 database to Magento 2 database.

I just want to know it will also migrate the disabled products from Magento 1?

Answer (score 2):

**YES**, Magento migrates disabled products as well.

I have migrated many databases and as per my experience, all products were migrated.

Hope above statement will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: welcome @Aji....:)